# generate float with leading zeroes and string with trailing space

Tags: rust

I'm trying to print out rows where the string "name" has a fixed length of 20 (trailing spaces).

I then want to generate a float number (amount) with 10 whole numbers and 8 decimals, problem is I cant figure out how to format the amount/float with leading zeroes making them the same length, also for some reason currently all the decimals becomes zero.

**The output I want:**

```
John Doe            D4356557654354645634564563.15343534
John Doe            C5674543545645634565456345.34535767
John Doe            C0000000000000000000000000.44786756
John Doe            D0000000000000000000865421.12576545
```

**What the output currently looks like:**

```
John Doe            12345678912345C390571360.00000000
John Doe            12345678912345D5000080896.00000000
John Doe            12345678912345C4320145.50000000
John Doe            12345678912345C1073856384.00000000
```

**Code**

```
use rand::Rng;
use pad::PadStr;

struct Report {
    name: String,
    account_number: i64,
    letter: char,
    amount: f32,
}

fn main() {

  let mut n = 1;
  let mut rng = rand::thread_rng();

  while n < 101 {
    let acc = Report {
        name: String::from("John Doe").pad_to_width(20),
        account_number: 12345678912345,
        letter: rng.gen_range('C'..='D'),
        amount: rng.gen_range(100.1..9999999999.9),
    };


    println!("{}{}{}{:.8}\n", acc.name, acc.account_number, acc.letter, acc.amount);
    n += 1;
  }

  }
```

https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=e229dbd212a94cd9cc0be507568c48d5

(for some reason "pad" is not working at playground)

Comment: What is `D4356557654354645634564563.144.85343534` even supposed to be? It has multiple dots in it ...

Comment: Please provide "expected outputs" actually have anything to do with your question. Also, please don't ask multiple questions at once. You are currently asking why left padding on strings doesn't work, how to print fixed length floats and why your randomly generated floats are whole numbers.

Comment: Sorry, it was an typo, have now edited and fixed it.

Comment: And why do your "expected outputs" have a "D" or "C" at a different position as your current output?

Comment: What do you mean with *'I then want to generate a float number'*? Of a specific distribution? If not, why not just generate two integers and put a dot in between?

Answer (score 1):

The reason you don't see any after-comma values is that `f32` does not have enough precision to represent the value you would like to print. In fact, no commonly used base-2 float has the precision you need here, converting from base 10 to base 2 back and forth with fractional numbers will always result in rounding errors.

For example, if you represent '9876543210.12345678' (a number your string can represent) in [`IEEE-754` 32-bit floats](https://www.h-schmidt.net/FloatConverter/IEEE754.html) (which `f32` is), you get:

- Desired value: `9876543210.12345678`
- Most accurate representation: `9876543488.00000000`
- Error due to conversion: `277.87654322`
- Binary Representation: `01010000 00010011 00101100 00000110`
- Hexadecimal Representation: `0x50132c06`

Even `f64` [still makes errors](https://www.binaryconvert.com/result_double.html?decimal=057056055054053052051050049048046049050051052053054055056):

- Desired value: `9876543210.12345678`
- Value actually stored in double: `9876543210.1234569549560546875`
- Error due to conversion: `0.0000001749560546854`
- Binary Representation: `01000010 00000010 01100101 10000000 10110111 01010000 11111100 11010111`
- Hexadecimal Representation: `0x42026580B750FCD7`

Don't use floats for this task. Use integers instead. For example two integers that can then be printed with a dot in between.

If you really do need the actual value, use a [decimal float](https://docs.rs/rust_decimal/latest/rust_decimal/struct.Decimal.html) instead, so it can actually represent the values you are trying to encode.

Another alternative would be to use fixed point integers. In other words, shift all values of your numbers by 8 decimals and represent them as an integer. Then, add the dot again when printing them. In your case you are lucky; if you store `9876543210.12345678` as the integer `987654321012345678`, it still fits into 64 bits, so you can use a `u64` to represent it. In fact, given that your example seems to be talking about an amount of money, this is most likely how it was intended.

---

**Example**:

- Don't use `pad` for padding. It's already built into Rust's `format` macro: `format!("{:<20}", "John Doe")`

```rust
use rand::Rng;

#[derive(Debug)]
struct MoneyAmount(u64);

impl MoneyAmount {
    fn as_value_string(&self) -> String {
        let mut s = format! {"{:>018}", self.0};
        s.insert(10, '.');
        s
    }
}

struct Report {
    name: String,
    account_number: i64,
    letter: char,
    amount: MoneyAmount,
}

fn main() {
    let mut rng = rand::thread_rng();

    for _ in 0..10 {
        let acc = Report {
            name: "John Doe".to_string(),
            account_number: 12345678912345,
            letter: rng.gen_range('C'..='D'),
            amount: MoneyAmount(rng.gen_range(100100000000..999999999999999999)),
        };

        println!(
            "{:<20}{}{}{}",
            acc.name,
            acc.account_number,
            acc.letter,
            acc.amount.as_value_string()
        );
    }
}
```

```
John Doe            12345678912345D3628299098.68538932
John Doe            12345678912345C5874745565.85000457
John Doe            12345678912345C6337870441.26543580
John Doe            12345678912345D1215442576.70454002
John Doe            12345678912345C3402018622.70996714
John Doe            12345678912345C7999783867.43749281
John Doe            12345678912345D5797682336.45356635
John Doe            12345678912345D1707577080.35404025
John Doe            12345678912345D5813907399.04925935
John Doe            12345678912345C0611246390.19108372
```